# CSS: import/copy style from another selector

Tags: css

let's say I have some markup generated by a server side 3rd party library (I cannot change that markup because it's 3rd party generated):

```
<div class="ICannotChangeThatClass">Awesome markup</div>
```

And let's say I want to apply on it some CSS from another 3rd party, **without modifying selector** (because it's 3rd party CSS):

```
.MyAwesomeClass {
    /* Some awesome CSS stuff */
}
```

Can I apply MyAwesomeClass to ICannotChangeThatClass **with pure CSS**?
I don't know how this could be, but something like:

```
.ICannotChangeThatClass {
    use .MyAwesomeClass /* this is invalid CSS */
    /* or maybe */
    extend .MyAwesomeClass /* this is invalid CSS */
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hi you can include other css file in your css file by using the import command
 @import url("other.css");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do it in pure css, only with css pre-processors like sass/less etc.

There are 2 ways you can go about it:

1. If you can control the generated html, add your class to the element: `<div class="ICannotChangeThatClass MyAwesomeClass ">Awesome markup</div>`
2. In your css, define a class with the same name as the one you want to override and add the new styling:

   ```
   .ICannotChangeThatClass {
       //MyAwsomeClass code goes here
    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If you add css to the class it will be combined into one in the end. It will not overwrite unless you add an attribute that already exists.

```
.ICannotChangeThatClass {
  /* Some awesome CSS stuff */
}
```

Answer (score -2):

If you apply two classes to an element like `class="firstclass secondclass"`, then those two classes are both applied in the order you give (alongside the usual rules on [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)).

Otherwise, you could look into a preprocessor like [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/) or [LESS](http://lesscss.org/), which do allow you to "extend" one CSS class within another, amongst a huge number of other useful features.

I highly recommend getting to grips with a pre-processor - they can make CSS much easier to write, especially in large projects.